# "The program 'javac' can be found...."

Tags: java, linux, java-8, linux-mint

My problem:

```
The program 'javac' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jdk
 * ecj
 * gcj-4.8-jdk
 * openjdk-7-jdk
 * gcj-4.6-jdk
 * openjdk-6-jdk
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

I am still new to Linux. Right now I on Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon 64-bit. I don't remember which guide I used to install the oracle version but my javac for it is located at: /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_74/bin.

now I have tried multiple solutions on stack overflow with no progress. (also note, I rather not use openjdk, but if I have too....anyways what I have done..

1) A lot of guides I have read about installing oracle version of java is installed in a location such as:  /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_xx or something similar. So due to this, I don't understand how to apply some of the commands to my location since there seems to be other factors / files I can't find in my java location

2) i have read a few different path solutions such as export $Path=".."  and etc, or edit profile or edit bashrc and etc with no luck but I could easily not have been doing this correctly since the guides seem to be not for beginners

3) most solutions have suggested just installing openjdk which I rather not

4) this solution i have not been able to figure out, and that is creating a soft link

so please, any help will be appreciated, so to verify,

OS: Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon 64-bit
JDK Location:  /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_74/bin. 
Openjdk: should have been removed per instructions i did to install orcale version

Comment: Have you tried [How to install Oracle Java on Ubuntu 14.04?](http://askubuntu.com/q/521145/84445).

Comment: @KshitizSharma, I have not, it seems like the install directories are different than mine, if I were to do this, could anything go wrong with having it already installed in a another dir?

Comment: Nope. Try following the manual install instructions. Change directory names as relevant. For example, you can install in /usr/lib/jvm or /opt/jdk8. Doesn't make a difference.

Comment: This worked, thank you! I mean, i turned on my PC and did it and it worked so I hope that was really it but thanks!

Comment: That's good to hear. If you want, you could post the steps that you followed here as an answer, to help other Mint users who'd need this.

Comment: I just went of the link, the link took me to the oracle tut which was the same steps so I just did it. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some “red flags” to watch out for?

Also ensure your JAVA_HOME variable has been set to:

/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
For this you can use the following command (see step 3 of Manual Install to see how to make it permanent):

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

https://askubuntu.com/questions/521145/how-to-install-oracle-java-on-ubuntu-14-04